# Is the cofinite topology on a countable set first countable?

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

Is the cofinite topology on a countable set first countable? I know it is not first countable on R but I don't know the case of a countable set.

Comment: How many sets are there in this topology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only is it first countable, it's second countable!  That's because there are only countably many finite subsets of a countable set.

For instance, suppose the elements of the set are the naturals, since there would be a bijection between them.  Then every finite subset could be paired with a different rational number, in a natural way.  Say the rational number, in binary, with zero to the left of the decimal, and ones in the $n$-th place after the decimal, zeros elsewhere.

But, then we have an injection into the rationals, which are countable.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but how can I prove formally that the cofinite topology on a countable set is second countable?

Comment: I gave a proof that there are only countably many finite subsets of a countable set.  That proves there are only countably many cofinite sets.  Thus there are only countably many sets in this topology.  Thus it most certainly has a countable basis (you could even take the topology itself), and so is second countable.