# How can I prove that the cofinite topology on a countable set is first countable?

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

Is the cofinite topology on a countable set first countable? I know it is not first countable on R but I don't know how to prove that it is first countable on a countable set.

Answer (score 5):

A countable set has only countably many finite subsets. And thus a cofinite topology on a countable set has only countably many open subsets. In particular it is both first and second countable.

Comment: This question is closed and downvoted, can you copy your answer to this [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3851061/is-the-cofinite-topology-on-a-countable-set-first-countable) ?